# How to assign a code to each document of Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I want to assign a small code string to each document after it is uploaded in alfresco. Something like: '2012/314-39414'.

The code will be generated by a rule that depends on the user that uploaded the document, the time the document is uploaded and a unique number which will be incremented after each document upload.

Can I have help to implement this in Alfresco?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the kind of site where people write your code, but where you receive help on your code.

Comment: @MarkRobinson: I didn't ask for code. I asked for design ideas. I'm not a newbie to Stackoverflow.com, I've seen Q/A here for over 2 years. And let alone questions which ask about design, there are plenty of questions that ask directly for code on a specific task. You can read more on what can be asked and what can not be asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: My apologies, I just looked at your rep, and figured you were new. So many new users do this, it's hard to tell the difference sometimes. My apologies again sir.

Comment: Please upvote this question again, as some people might think this is not a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OnCreateNodePolicy](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/node/NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy.html) (java code) to do this the cleanest way.

Search the net or Alfresco forums to look for examples or you could download the SDK and lookup current code which uses it.